# Visual Studio 2019 does not see such things as .StartReceiving () and others | Telegram-bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a simple Telegram bot on C #. I installed NuGet packages such as `Telegram.Bot` and `Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling`. I also watched a few video tutorials.

However, I have errors with `.StartReceiving()`, `.StopReceiving()`, `.OnMessage`, `MessageEventArgs.`, `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` and `KeyboardButton`.

And I don't know the reason for that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;
using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
using Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling;

namespace TelegramBot
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string Token { get; set; } = "My token";
        private static TelegramBotClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TelegramBotClient(Token);
            client.StartReceiving();
            client.OnMessage += OnMessageHandler;
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static async void OnMessageHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;

            if (msg.Text != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Received a message with the text: {msg.Text}");
                switch (msg.Text)
                {
                    case "Sticke":
                        await client.SendStickerAsync(
                            chatId: msg.Chat.Id,
                            sticker: "Link for a sticker",
                            replyToMessageId: msg.MessageId,
                            replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;

                    case "Sticker":
                        await client.SendPhotoAsync(
                            chatId: msg.Chat.Id,
                            photo: "Link for a pic",
                            replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;

                    default:
                        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Chat.Id, "select a command: ", replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IReplyMarkup GetButtons()
        {
            return new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
            {
                Keyboard = new List<List<KeyboardButton>>
                {
                    new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "Sticker"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "Pic"} },
                    new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "123"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "456"} }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting? Something along the lines of: 'TelegramBotClient' does not contain a definition for 'StopReceiving' ?

Answer (score 0):

So I know you probably watched a lot of tutorials about this and maybe those were a little outdated, but actually the way you handle messages has changed quite a bit.

Let me show how I do this:

```cs
    client.StartReceiving(async (bot, update, token) => {
          if (update.Message is Message message)
          {
             await client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "hello world!");
          }
    });
```

In the code above I used a lambda expression, which is much more readable imo. But you can still use whatever way you prefer the most.